# Change cell color when date is older than one year

Tags: vba, date

I made a Userform where i can enter my data like product ID, place,..,  in the Column „G“ i have the Date(e.g.20.4.2005)(Range is from G2 to G100) - i have bought something. When the typed Date is longer than one year the cellcolor should be turned to red, can somebody help me please?

Comment: You don't need VBA for that, just use conditional formatting, right?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't really an appropriate question for this site, please see. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I literally Googled "Change cell color when date is older than one year" and got a zillon results... could have saved you some typing :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Conditional formating is much better. It work on realtime, right after a cell's value is update. Here's the operation:

- Select range G2 to G100
- Select tab Home -> Conditional formating -> New rule
- "Select rule type" selectbox: Format only cell that contain
- Set condition for "Edit the rule Description": Cell Value -> Greater than -> Input the date you wanna compare
- Click button Format -> Fill -> Select background colour that you wish
- Click OK, OK

Comment: Hi thanks but, i need i with vba because i habe a UssrForm, conditional formating is already okay, it doesnt work together with conditional formating ..

Comment: The code is like `If ActiveCell.Value > Cells(1, "A").Value Then ActiveCell.Interior.Color = 255` (Replace ActiveCell and Cells(1, "A") with the cell that you put your date value to compare)